# How do I create a table with PascalCase notation in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to create a table in Amazon Redshift with PascalCase notation. How do I achieve this?

E.g.: I want the table name to be `"EmployeeDetails"` and not as default way in which it gets created as `"employeedetails"`.

Comment: While [there are ways to do it](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_names.html), I would strongly recommend **not** to do it. Use "snake case" instead: `emplyee_details` - it will save you a lot of trouble in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

Identifiers and names in Redshift are case-insensitive.

> Standard and delimited identifiers are case-insensitive and are folded
>   to lower case. Identifiers must consist of only UTF-8 printable
>   characters.

[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_names.html)

I recommend using snake_case, as @a_horse_with_no_name suggested. This is the standard way of doing it.